# triple integration in the positive ocatant

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$\iiint_
V
(x^2 + y^2) .dx .dy .dz$$
where V is the region in the positive octant bounded by the sphere $r = a$.

I have worked out the change of the coordinates and simplified the question but I am stuck on the limits for $\theta$ and $\phi$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use the cylindric coordinates.

details:

then 
$$
\iint (x^2+y^2) dxdy =\int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \int_0^{\sqrt{a^2 - z^2}} r^3dr
= \frac {\pi}{2}\frac{(a^2 - z^2)^2}{4} = \frac{\pi(a^2 - z^2)^2}{8}
\\
\iiint (x^2+y^2)dxdydz = \frac\pi 8
\int_0^a (a^2 - z^2)^2 dz
$$

Comment: but I have used spherical polar coordintates because we are given a shpere in the question?

Comment: the term $x^2+y^2$ breaks the spherical symetry. But it becomes $r^2$ in the cylindrical coordinates.